# Issue regarding exception details c#

Tags: c#, exception

I was trying to capture exception details with the below code, but it is not giving error in details.

I was trying to download a file from our ftp server with code like ftp classes. When file was not found, I fire the above method and pass in the exception. Unfortunately the method printed the following:

```
Error occured and Error details as follows
Exception occured in file 
Exception occured in method SyncRequestCallback
Exception occured in line & column number 0 0
```

Here is my code. How can I capture the exception details (e.g. line number, method where the exception was thrown, etc.)?

```
public static string GetException(Exception ex)
{
    //Get a StackTrace object for the exception
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
    //Get the first stack frame
    StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);
    //Get the file name
    string fileName = frame.GetFileName();
    //Get the method name
    string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;
    //Get the line number from the stack frame
    int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
    //Get the column number
    int col = frame.GetFileColumnNumber();

    string strBody = "Hi,<br/><br/>";
    strBody = strBody + "Error occured and Error details as follows<br/>";
    strBody = strBody + "Error message " + ex.Message + "<br/>";
    strBody = strBody + "Exception occured in file " + fileName + "<br/>";
    strBody = strBody + "Exception occured in method " + methodName + "<br/>";
    strBody = strBody + "Exception occured in line & column number " + line + " " + col + "<br/><br/>Thanks";
    return strBody;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `ex.ToString()`?

Comment: Just in addition, you should also check the inner exception since the error could be a result of another error being thrown.

Comment: You should use the FileNotFoundException instead of Exception for this specific case where the file is not found.

Comment: Well, I see a method name: `SyncRequestCallback`. You should examine the entire call stack to locate the root cause of your exception.

Comment: how to capture line no & method name from where exception occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to capture more information you'll need to deploy `.pdb`  files generated on build. This will allow you to know specific line where error happened.

As a side note, it seems to me that you're reinventing the wheel creating such a complex logic to log. There plenty of frameworks that will do the dirty job for you as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Comment: To expand, when running from dll, line numbers and files names don't exists. Thus the .pdb.

Comment: @Thomas: not sure what you mean with that, the same I said on my answer applies.

Comment: i have develop a console apps by which i download file from our ftp server. so when error occur then i want to show method name and error line no from where exception occur.how to capture line no & method name from where exception occur? just guide me.

Comment: @Thomas: when you build your project, on the output folder, you'll see a file with the same name of your exe but with pdb extension. You'll need to deploy that file with your exe file. As other people pointed out using `ex.ToString()` could replace your method `GetException`

Comment: the pdf file is there in debug folder and i am running my apps in debug mode. so else i need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ToString` on an exception generally generates a readable version of the public details. And only the details available to the exception will be shown, so if the app is not running in debug mode and doesn't have corresponding *.pdb files (or you don't have them to attach, after the fact) - and symbols loads - then you can't get detailed source information.

Comment: just as a note: there is no need to run on release mode to get the line number, pdb files are enough

Comment: i have develop a console apps by which i download file from our ftp server. so when error occur then i want to show method name and error line no from where exception occur.how to capture line no & method name from where exception occur? just guide me.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Terminology, I guess; generally it's the _configuration of the build_ which dictates how the thing is compiled, usually with the "Release" omitting the pdbs etc.

Comment: By default Visual Studio will generate pdb files on release mode. In any case, just wanted to remark that it's not necessary to deploy in debug mode, you can deploy in release as long as you include pdb files.